# Search with responsive design... Width 100%?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, search-engine

I am trying to design a search engine that is responsive design but i have a problem with the search button and the textbox when the length of the window decreases. I do not know if I could help me. I want the textbox and button together occupy 100% of my container

This is what I've come up with:
https://jsfiddle.net/wfbchc1y/

```css
.mainBox{
 max-width: 800px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: solid 1px #D5D4D4;
 background-color: #FFF;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:20px;
}
#txtSearch{
 height: 40px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 border: solid 1px #CBCBCB;
 border-radius: 4px;
 outline: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #6D6A6A;
 width: 92%;
 float: left;
}

#btnSearch{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 outline:none;
 cursor:pointer;
 transition:All .5s ease;
 border:solid 1px #000;
 background-color:#009;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="mainBox">
  <input type="text" name="peticion" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearch">
  <input type="button" value=">" id="btnSearch">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to calculate the width of input.

```
width: calc(92% - 40px);//92% - width of input
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/wfbchc1y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use display flex on the main container.

```css
.mainBox{
 max-width: 800px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: solid 1px #D5D4D4;
 background-color: #FFF;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:20px;
        display: flex;
        

}
#txtSearch{
 height: 40px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 border: solid 1px #CBCBCB;
 border-radius: 4px;
 outline: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #6D6A6A;
 width: 92%;
 float: left;
}

#btnSearch{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 outline:none;
 cursor:pointer;
 transition:All .5s ease;
 border:solid 1px #000;
 background-color:#009;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="mainBox">
  <input type="text" name="peticion" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearch">
  <input type="button" value=">" id="btnSearch">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solved!

```css
.mainBox{
    position:relative;
 max-width: 800px;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 outline: solid 1px #D5D4D4;
 border: solid 20px #fff;
 background-color: #FFF;
 margin:0 auto;
}
#txtSearch{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
 height: 40px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 border: solid 1px #CBCBCB;
 border-radius: 4px;
 outline: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #6D6A6A;
 width: 88%;
}

#btnSearch{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 outline:none;
    width: 10%;
 cursor:pointer;
 transition:All .5s ease;
 border:solid 1px #000;
 background-color:#009;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="mainBox">
  <input type="text" name="peticion" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearch">
  <input type="button" value=">" id="btnSearch">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code.

```css
.mainBox{
 max-width: 800px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: solid 1px #D5D4D4;
 background-color: #FFF;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:20px;
}
#txtSearch{
    width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 border: solid 1px #CBCBCB;
 border-radius: 4px;
 outline: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #6D6A6A;
 float: left;
}

#btnSearch{
    width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 outline:none;
 cursor:pointer;
 transition:All .5s ease;
 border:solid 1px #000;
 background-color:#009;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBox">
  <table width="100%">
     <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="peticion" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearch"></td>
         <td width="5px">&nbsp;</td>
         <td width="75px"><input type="button" value=">" id="btnSearch"></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```